# VBA If Statement and For Loop moving to the cell below

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement, for-loop

I have 3 columns in my xlSheet

```
Year      GapYear   Col3
Year 13   Yes       2018
Year 12   No    
Year 13   Yes   
Year 12   No
```

I want vba to work out the start year in col3 based on my if statement logic:

```
Sub startYear()


Dim Year As Range
Set Year = Range("A2")

Dim GapYear As Range
Set GapYear = Range("B2")

Dim Col3 As Range
Set Col3 = Range("C2")



lastRow = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
For Row = 1 To lastRow


     If Year = "Year 13" And GapYear = "Yes" Then Col3 = "2018"
     If Year = "Year 13" And GapYear = "No" Then Col3 = "2017"
     If Year = "Year 12" And GapYear = "Yes" Then Col3 = "2019"
     If Year = "Year 12" And GapYear = "No" Then Col3 = "2018"


Next Row

End Sub
```

The code only works out cell C2 and doesn't move down to work out the other rows. I have tried changing the ranges to the whole column e.g. Range("C:C") but I get a type mismatch error. I have also tried adding activecell.offset(1,0)  in the for loop which moves the activecell down but cell C3 remains blank.

I have hundreds of entries in columns A (Year) and B (GapYear), how can I get the code to work through each row and give the correct answer in col3?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to redefine the ranges you are checking each time the row increases. The way you do that is below:

```
Sub startYear()

Dim Year As Range, GapYear As Range, Col3 As Range

lastRow = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count

For Row = 1 To lastRow
  Set Year = Range("A" & Row)
  Set GapYear = Range("B" & Row)
  Set Col3 = Range("C" & Row)
  If Year = "Year 13" And GapYear = "Yes" Then Col3 = "2018"
  If Year = "Year 13" And GapYear = "No" Then Col3 = "2017"
  If Year = "Year 12" And GapYear = "Yes" Then Col3 = "2019"
  If Year = "Year 12" And GapYear = "No" Then Col3 = "2018"

Next Row

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Just doing a loop does not change the variables that you have hard coded.

```
Sub startYear()

Dim rw As Long

With ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet
    LastRow = .UsedRange.Rows.Count
    For rw = 2 To LastRow
         If .Cells(rw, 1) = "Year 13" And .Cells(rw, 2) = "Yes" Then .Cells(rw, 3) = "2018"
         If .Cells(rw, 1) = "Year 13" And .Cells(rw, 2) = "No" Then .Cells(rw, 3) = "2017"
         If .Cells(rw, 1) = "Year 12" And .Cells(rw, 2) = "Yes" Then .Cells(rw, 3) = "2019"
         If .Cells(rw, 1) = "Year 12" And .Cells(rw, 2) = "No" Then .Cells(rw, 3) = "2018"
    Next Row
End With

End Sub
```